# Redirect to custom login page from Form's Authentication login page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to redirect to the login page when redirecting it dynamically. 
I have set the loginUrl to a page (FormAuthRedirection.aspx) in web.config. Now, In this page, I am redirecting it to a login page (This login page was set earlier in web.config), it could be different url for different clients.
Issue is, its not redirecting to the login page. Instead, it comes to the same page 5 times and web site is not working.

Please help me to identify the reason why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a wierd situation, but I guess it should work.  Only thing I can think of is... Make sure your 'final' login page does not require authorized access.

Comment: There's a good change it's your problem. By the way, make sure you pass the returnUrl parameter to you custom login page to be sure the user will be properly redirected after login